# javascript private method reference inside immediately invoked function

Tags: javascript

This javascript code needs to take in a sentence, extract the first word, and call  a function named as that first word, but do nothing if no function is present for that word. But is it not compiling. Any idea why and how to fix it?
i.e. how can I pass the parameters to the function?

```
refactor = (function () {

  const john = function (description) {
    console.log(description);
  };

  const factoring = {
    'john': john(description) // <--- description is not defined ---

  };

  return Object.freeze({
    'byName': function (description) {  // calls the correct private method if present
      let name = description.match(/(\S+)\s/)[1];
      if (name in factoring) factoring[name](description);
    }
  });
}());
```

Comment: The error says it all. `desc` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: What would `desc` even be?

Comment: Then, how can I pass the parameters to the function?

Comment: I think it should be `const factoring = { john };`

Comment: @zerkms yes, that fixed it,  `const factoring = {'john': john}`

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is not defined. Either define `desc` and give it a value (`const desc = "Some random string"`) or replace `desc` with some value (`'john': john("Some random string")`).

Comment: But that value is not available, it is only available in run time.

Comment: @FredJ. for it to be available it should be declared first.

Comment: @FredJ. zerkms is right. Sorry, I'm used to regular JS rather than ECMAScript

Comment: @LeoWilson—how is "regular JS" different to ECMAScript in regard to reference errors?